# allen-sdk get_flourescence_timeStamps

Tags: python, allen-sdk, nwb

I believe I am downloading the NWB files properly as I am able to get the df/F traces and stimuli information without trouble. However, I am receiving an error when I try to call "get_running_speed":

AttributeError: 'BrainObservatoryNwbDataSet' object has no attribute 'get_flourescence_timeStamps'

I receive the same error when I call the "get_fourescence_timeStamps" function as well. I have updated the allen sdk packages, so I should be working with the most current version of the software.

Is this a problem anyone else can replicate?

Answer (score 1):

Is the spelling in your question correct?  `get_flourescence_timeStamps` with the capital 'S' is not a function.  Neither is `get_fourescence_timeStamps` with a missing `l`.

Here's where that function is called inside of `get_running_speed`:

https://github.com/AllenInstitute/AllenSDK/blob/master/allensdk/core/brain_observatory_nwb_data_set.py#L807

It looks like it's spelled correctly.  Here's the definition of `get_fluorescence_timestamps`:

https://github.com/AllenInstitute/AllenSDK/blob/master/allensdk/core/brain_observatory_nwb_data_set.py#L256

Could you post a small code snippet that reproduces your error?

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply.It appears that I did not update properly, as I have re-copied the sdk files from github and get_running_speed() is now working.

Comment: I also receive a printed line when I download the experiments, "...Downloading URL:...", which I did not receive previously. I expect something weird happened the last time I attempted to update. Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not sure what was going on before, but I'm glad that it's working for you now!